# Asynchronous function within for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a two dimensional array name:*final_draft_arr* and I am looping through each element of this array and calling a function name:**getFileContentAsBase64** with each element of the array. The function is asynchronous and the for is finish before the function is executed properly for each element. How to solve this asynchronous behavior. I want the function to execute before the loop goes to its next iteration. The codes are given below.

```
    getFileContentAsBase64:async function(path,callback){
        await window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, gotFile);                  
        function gotFile(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.file(function(file) {
               var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                 var content = this.result;
                 callback(content);
                };
                  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         });
       }
     },

    base64ToBlob:function(base64, mime) { 
        mime = mime || '';
        var sliceSize = 1024;
        var byteChars = window.atob(base64);
        var byteArrays = [];

        for (var offset = 0, len = byteChars.length; offset < len; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteChars.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }
        return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: mime});
    }, 

  //this is the loop
   var final_draft_arr = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
   $.each(final_draft_arr, function(key, value){
      var i_dat = new FormData();                                                                                                               
      var data_id_no = final_draft_arr[key][0];                                                                                                         
      var sub_arr_len = final_draft_arr[key].length;
      for(j=1; j < sub_arr_len; j++){                                                
         getFileContentAsBase64(final_draft_arr[key][j],function(base64Image){
            var base64ImageContent = base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, ""); 
            var blob_new = base64ToBlob(base64ImageContent, 'image/png');                                                                     
            i_dat.append('Bilder[]', blob_new);

        });                                                 
     }

  });
```

Comment: you need an await on the getFileContentAsbase64 function and the loop to be inside an async function. Also swap your $.each to a for loop. Not sure if you can do an await inside a $.each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async function as a callback and await the asynchronous function call.

```
$.each(final_draft_arr, async function(key, value){
  var i_dat = new FormData();                                                                                                               
  var data_id_no = final_draft_arr[key][0];                                                                                                         
  var sub_arr_len = final_draft_arr[key].length;
  for(j=1; j < sub_arr_len; j++){                                                
     await getFileContentAsBase64(final_draft_arr[key][j],function(base64Image){
        var base64ImageContent = base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, ""); 
        var blob_new = base64ToBlob(base64ImageContent, 'image/png');                                                                     
        i_dat.append('Bilder[]', blob_new);

    });                                                 
 }
});
```